# adding Sliding effects to my images on React

Tags: reactjs, image, styled-components, slide, effect

I want to add some sliding effects so that the image in the background of the hero section changes overtime between six images on React JS

I use some styled-components animation which gives a great result **but the problem there are white flashes between the images**
my React Code:

```
  return (
    <IntroContainer scroll={scrollVal}>
       
        <ValueText>If your business is selected, our team of developers will build you a digital tool that takes your business to the next level.
        </ValueText>
      
        <BenefitsList>
          <BenefitsHeader>BENEFITS</BenefitsHeader> 
          <ListItem>Open-Source Engineers</ListItem> 
          <ListItem>Partner with a Nonprofit</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Custom Tools (Need Image)</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Meet your Needs (Need Image)</ListItem>
          <ListItem>Gain an Advantage (Need Image)</ListItem>
        </BenefitsList>

   </IntroContainer>

  );
```

my styled-components code:

```
const breatheAnimation = keyframes`
0% { background-image : url(${imageList[0]})}  
4% { background-image: url(${imageList[0]})}  
12% {background-image :url(${imageList[1]})}     
38% {background-image :url(${imageList[2]})}    
52% {background-image :url(${imageList[3]})}     
68% {background-image :url(${imageList[4]})}     
94% {background-image :url(${imageList[5]})}     
100% {background-image :url(${imageList[0]})}     
`
export const IntroContainer = styled.div`
height: auto;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify:content:center;
min-height: 45vh;
animation-name: ${breatheAnimation};
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-duration: 20s;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size:cover;
background-position: 0px ${props=>props.scroll}px;
z-index: -1;
`;
```

Comment: You can't animate a new url property. The best way would be to use classes with CSS to animate them (either with opacity, or transforms).

Comment: You can add a carousel of images either by [yourself](https://medium.com/tinyso/how-to-create-the-responsive-and-swipeable-carousel-slider-component-in-react-99f433364aa0) or using some [third party packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)